# cocos2d running animation once weird error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:reloadSpeed]; 
CCFiniteTimeAction *animFinite = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCRepeat *repeatAction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:animFinite times:1];
id animDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneAnimatingOnce)];
[self.person runAction:[CCSequence actions:repeatAction, animDone, nil]];
```

The above code never reaches the function "doneAnimatingOnce"
but the below code does, so i feel there's something wrong with the finiteTimeAction

```
//CCFiniteTimeAction *animFinite = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
//CCRepeat *repeatAction = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:animFinite times:1];
id animDone = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneAnimatingOnce)];
[self.person runAction:[CCSequence actions:animDone, nil]];
```

All i'd like to do is run the sprite sheet animation once, but i've been struggling with this for about 4 hours, can someone please help?

```
CCFiniteTimeAction *animFinite = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
    id animDone = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneAnimatingOnce)];
    [self.person runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:animFinite two:animDone]];
```

that runs the animation but the function is still never called

Answer (score 0):

If you want your animation to be run once, you don't need any `CCRepeat` action. Try something like this.-

```
CCAnimation *anim = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames delay:reloadSpeed]; 
CCFiniteTimeAction *animFinite = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCCallFunc *animDone = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(doneAnimatingOnce)];
[self.person runAction:[CCSequence actionOne:animFinite two:animDone]];
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it exactly this way, it still never made it to the doneAnimatingOnce function

Comment: Mmh not sure, but I think `CCCallFuncN` (notice the last N), expects a selector with one param, so the selector should be `doneAnimatingOnce:` (with an ending colon). Did you try `CCCallFunc` with no N?

Comment: Yea i tried CCCallFunc with no N or :, still the same results :/ The animation doesnt run either

Comment: Well, if the animation itself doesn't run, the problem may be in the `CCAnimate` action indeed. Since the code seems to be ok, please, double-check that `animFrames` and reloadSpeed have the expected values.

Comment: I got it to run the animation, the function still doesnt run, i updated the post @ssantos